# Read Categorical Value split in Random forest in R

Tags: r, tree, random-forest

I have a dataset which contains various categorical variables and no numeric variable. I converted the variables to ordered factors by:

```
df$colA= factor(df$colA,levels=unique(df$colA), ordered=TRUE)
```

Now I am making a random forest model and then making a tree using below code:

```
getTree(model.rf, 1, labelVar=TRUE) #model.rf is the model created using df and various columns
```

I get the tree something like below:

```
        left daughter   right daughter   split var  split point   status    prediction
1                   2           3               colA        1.5         1        <NA>


2                   4           5               colB         2.5         1       <NA>
```

and so on....

## Ask:

Both my split var are ordered factor categorical variables. Now how do I interpret split point as 1.5 or 2.5. I can't say the split is between two groups.

To explain it further: Lets say `ColA` is Gender with levels as `M` or `F` and `ColB` is `Weight` with levels as `High` `Medium` `Low`.

Now to explain it to stakeholders I can't say when the **gender is between Male and Female and the Weight is between Medium to High**

**Can someone help me in how to explain RF tree when dealing with categorical variable?**

Comment: You don't explain a RF model, that's not the purpose of a RF. You would have to interpret all the individual trees, which are built on bootstrap samples. If your goal is interpretation you need a different model.

Comment: I am trying to interpret the various trees built by RF

Comment: You don't do that, RF is a black box model and it is treated as such. You should build a decision tree if that is the objective.

Comment: Are you sure? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41443/how-to-actually-plot-a-sample-tree-from-randomforestgettree this says you can..

Comment: And in the second sentence you can read `Yes I know you're not supposed to do this operationally, RF is a blackbox, etc etc...`. What you are asking can certainly be achieved, that is visualize and interpret individual trees in a RF model, it's just that you don't do it. Just because you can do it does not mean you should do it, etc..

Comment: OK!! Got it!! So then I will build Decision tree to do so!!